# I am appending csv files in the format

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am appending multiple csv files from a path using python in this format

```
A  B  C  date
2  3  4  20180213
5  6  7  20170213

A  B  C  date
3  4  9  20170210
3  2  1  20180211
```

The code I am using is:

```
import os 
import datetime 
import glob 
import pandas as pd 
import csv 

yyyymmdd = (dt.date.today()-timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y%m%d') 

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join("/xyz/abc/*/*.csv")):
    df2=pd.read_csv(filename).assign(date=yyyymmdd)
    df2 = df2.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
    df2=df2.drop_duplicates()
    print(df2)
```

The result I am getting is :

```
A  B  C  date
2  3  4  20180213
5  6  7  20170213
A  B  C  date
3  4  9  20170210
3  2  1  20180211
```

i.e. the **headers getting repeated**.  Whereas I want it in the format:

```
A  B  C  date
2  3  4  20180213
5  6  7  20170213
3  4  9  20170210
3  2  1  20180211
```

Comment: How is *date* not the same for all rows per from your `assign` call? Also, `timedelta` is neither defined nor imported method. Be sure code is fully compilable for us to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to `header` parameter for the `read_csv` function [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), my suggestion is to skip the headers using `header=None` except for the first file.

Answer (score 0):

Consider building a list or dict of dataframes and then concatenate all list items together using [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with no issue of headers:

```
...
df_list = []

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join("/xyz/abc/*/*.csv")):
    tmp = pd.read_csv(filename).assign(new_date=yyyymmdd)
    df_list.append(tmp)        # LIST APPEND
    print(tmp)

final_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 0):

I got where I was going wrong. *print(df2)* was getting in the loop. Post removal of the tab before it, it worked.

```
import os 
import datetime 
import glob 
import pandas as pd 
import csv 

yyyymmdd = (dt.date.today()-timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y%m%d') 

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join("/xyz/abc/*/*.csv")):
    df2=pd.read_csv(filename).assign(date=yyyymmdd)
    df2 = df2.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
    df2=df2.drop_duplicates()
print(df2)
```